# React State not updating on key event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm running into an issue that I can't quite figure out. I'm building a Wordle clone, the state seems to be updating on some events and not on others, and I can't quite track down why.

I have a `Keyboard` component, which takes `handleKeyClick` as a prop from the parent component, and that is attached to two event handlers.

### Parent Component

```
import { Box, Divider, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import Keyboard from "../Keyboard";
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
import WordleNotifbar from "../WordleNotifBar";
import Loading from "../Utils/Loading";
import { IGuessState } from "../../types";

interface IGuessGridProps {
    addGuess: Function,
    guesses: any,
    answer: any
}
const GuessGrid = (props: IGuessGridProps) => {

    const { addGuess, guesses, answer } = props;
    let [notif, setNotif] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [guess, setGuess] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const styles = {
        input: {
            border: ".5px solid white",
            height: "50px",
            display: "flex",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            backgroundColor: "",
            color: "white",
        },
        container: {
            minWidth: "300px",
            width: "30%",
            maxWidth: "450px",
            margin: "0 auto",
            marginTop: "15px",
        },
    }

// In the parent component, I have defined the function I'm passing in as a prop as such: 
    const handleAddCharacter = (char: string) => {
        setGuess([...guess, char])
    }

// Not fully implemented yet 
    const handleBackspace = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setGuess([...guess])
    }

    const handleSubmit = (): void => {
        let word = guess.join('')
        if (word.length === answer.length) {
            addGuess(word.toLowerCase())
            setGuess([]);
        }
        else {
            setNotif(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setNotif(false);
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
    if (answer) {
        return <>
            <Divider />
            <Grid container sx={styles.container} >
                {answer.split('').map((_: string, index: number) => {
                    return (<Grid item xs={12 / answer.length} sx={styles.input} key={uuid()}>
                        <Box>
                            <Typography>
                                {guess[index]}
                            </Typography>
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>)
                })}
            </Grid>
            <Keyboard guesses={guesses} answer={answer} handleKeyClick={handleAddCharacter} handleBackspace={handleBackspace} submitFunc={handleSubmit} />
            {notif ? <WordleNotifbar message="Not Enough Characters" duration={1000} /> : ""}
        </>;
    } else {
        return <Loading />
    }
};

export default GuessGrid;
```

### Keyboard Component

```
import { Box, Grid, SxProps, Theme, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import BackspaceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Backspace';
import React from "react";

interface IKeyboardProps {
    guesses: string[],
    answer: string,
    handleKeyClick: any,
    submitFunc: any,
    handleBackspace: any
}
const Keyboard = (props: IKeyboardProps) => {
    const { guesses, answer, handleKeyClick, submitFunc, handleBackspace } = props
    const [guessedLetters, setGuessedLetters] = useState<string[]>();
    const topRow = 'qwertyuiop'.toUpperCase().split('');
    const middleRow = 'asdfghjkl'.toUpperCase().split('');
    const bottomRow = 'zxcvbnm'.toUpperCase().split('');
    const allKeys = topRow.concat(middleRow.concat(bottomRow));

// When the component is initialized, I am establishing an event listener in the window for the key press events.

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keypress', handlePhysicalKeyPress)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        const allGuessedCharacters = guesses.join('').split('');
        const uniqueGuessedCharacters = allGuessedCharacters.filter((val: string, index: number, self) => self.indexOf(val) === index)
        setGuessedLetters(uniqueGuessedCharacters);
    }, [guesses])

    const handleVirtualKeyPress = (e: any) => {
        handleKeyClick(e.target.textContent)
    }

    const handlePhysicalKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (allKeys.includes(e.key.toUpperCase())) {
            handleKeyClick(e.key.toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    const genKeyStyles = (character: string, _: number): SxProps<Theme> => {
        character = character.toLowerCase()
        const styles = {
            width: character === "bs" || character === "enter" ? "63px" : "33px",
            marginX: "1px",
            marginY: "1px",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            height: "50px",
            color: "black",
            textAlign: "center",
            backgroundColor: "#DDD",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
        };
        if (guessedLetters) {
            if (answer.indexOf(character) >= 0 && guessedLetters.indexOf(character) >= 0) {
                styles.backgroundColor = "green"
            } else if (answer.indexOf(character) < 0 && guessedLetters.indexOf(character) >= 0) {
                styles.backgroundColor = "#777"
            }
        }
        return styles
    }

    return <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "10px", }}>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            {topRow.map((letter: string, index: any) => {
                return (
                    <Box sx={genKeyStyles(letter, index)} key={uuid()} onClick={handleVirtualKeyPress}>
                        <Typography key={uuid()}>{letter}</Typography>
                    </Box>
                )
            })}
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            {middleRow.map((letter: string, index: any) => {
                return (
                    <Box sx={genKeyStyles(letter, index)} key={uuid()} onClick={handleVirtualKeyPress}>
                        <Typography key={uuid()}>{letter}</Typography>
                    </Box>
                )
            })}
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Box sx={genKeyStyles("enter", 1)} key={uuid()} onClick={submitFunc}>
                <Typography key={uuid()}>enter</Typography>
            </Box>

            {bottomRow.map((letter: string, index: any) => {
                return (
                    <Box sx={genKeyStyles(letter, index)} key={uuid()} onClick={handleVirtualKeyPress}>
                        <Typography key={uuid()}>{letter}</Typography>
                    </Box>
                )
            })}
            <Box sx={genKeyStyles("bs", 1)} key={uuid()} onClick={handleBackspace}>
                <Typography key={uuid()}><BackspaceIcon /></Typography>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    </Box>
};

export default Keyboard;
```

What happens is that the virtual key press seems to update the state properly, but the physical keypress seems to reset the state back to an empty array. I can't really figure out a good reason why this is happening. Any thoughts? I appreciate your help in advance!

[Link to Live Application](https://620010b7ccb6a12d4a2c780c--seven-letter-wordle.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keypress', handlePhysicalKeyPress)
    }, [])
```

...you are attaching a *specific* `handlePhysicalKeyPress` function as event listener. But that function is re-created at each component re-render, so you no longer reference the "current" function "version" (should you try to remove it, you would not be able to because it is no longer the same reference).

As such, the actual listener is the very first "version" of your function, which calls the very first "version" of your `handleKeyClick` prop, which is the very first "version" of your `handleAddCharacter` function, which knows only the very first version of your `guess` state... which is an empty array.

That is why when `handlePhysicalKeyPress` is executed by a key press, it builds a new guess array from an empty array.

While you should avoid this discrepancy between what you attach to your event listener and your actual "render-time" function, there should be a very simple solution to your specific case: should you use the [functional form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of your state setter, even if it is the "very first version", it should use the "current" state version:

```
setGuess((currentGuess) => [...currentGuess, char])
```

Comment: ah, interesting. thanks so much, this solution does seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: That solves my problem, thank you very much.

Very subtle. I think this is a relatively obscure React feature. It seems even typescript transpiler or eslint does not know about it, and gives a warning like: `Argument of type '(prev: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)`.

Comment: Hi @Ellis, thank you for your feedback! For your typing issue, you may have a specific situation. The 2nd returned element of `useState` should accept both forms ([demo](https://tsplay.dev/wOR5rW)). Please feel free to ask a new question with details of your issue if you need help.